# Why I can't get the custom header from Django request.META

Tags: python, django

When use `.\curl.exe -v -H 'HTTP_TEST:A17041708' http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test`

open the url.

I print the request.META,but i can't find my custom header in it

Comment: I resolved this quest ,the reason is the custom header should not contain underscore so I changed the underscore with dash and boom, everything started working. Hope this will help people like me. :-)

Comment: please consider putting this as an answer to your own question. This solved my problem but I nearly missed it because I was looking for a bona fide answer.

Answer (score 0):

The fields you define will be prefixed with HTTP.